# Php and jquery Dynamic to show and hide div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
I have a list of the conditions and i fetch their name and it works fine but i want when i click the condition name it description come below.

i have done that but it shows for only one can you help me for that
```

Here is html code which i use for showing the description of the record it always shows the last record.
when i add the record it add means works fine for adding
it also works fine for edit also for the delete
but if there is two record then every time it show the description of last record not on which i click
I want to show the description of the record which is clciked
    Thanks

```
    <div>
    <?php
     $query="select * from tbl_coditions where userId=".$_SESSION['userId'];
     $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $VisitDate=strtotime($row['DiagnosisDate']);
     $VisitDate=date("m-d-Y",$VisitDate);
     $userId=$row['userid'];
     $conditionId=$row['conditionId'];
    ?>
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a#p<?php if(isset($conditionId)) echo $conditionId; ?>").click(function(event){
     $("#HiddenDiv<?php if(isset($conditionId)) echo $conditionId; ?>").show();
     })    
     });
    </script>

<div id="AjaxDiv1">      

                              <div id="HiddenDiv<?php if(isset($conditionId)) echo $conditionId?>" style="display:none;">
                              <?php 
                              $query="select * from tbl_coditions where conditionId=$conditionId";
                              $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                              $query_result=mysql_fetch_array($result); 
                              $VisitDate=strtotime($query_result['DiagnosisDate']);
                              $VisitDate=date("m-d-Y",$VisitDate);                    
                              ?>
                              <div class="detailContainer panelContent">
  <div class="panelTitle" tabindex="-1">
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_Name_Row_RowContainer" class="detailRowContainer">
      <div class="detailRow">
        <div class="detailLeftColumn mxDetailsLabel"> Condition:
          <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_Name_Row_ValidatorContainer" class="detailErrorContainer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="detailRightColumn"> <span id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_Name_Row_ViewControl"><?php echo $query_result['ServiceName']; ?></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="detailContent">
    <div class="narrowTopContent">
      <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_DiagnosisDate_Row_RowContainer" class="detailRowContainer detailRowOdd">
        <div class="detailRow">
          <div class="detailLeftColumn mxDetailsLabel"> Diagnosis Date:
            <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_DiagnosisDate_Row_ValidatorContainer" class="detailErrorContainer"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="detailRightColumn"> <span id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_DiagnosisDate_Row_ViewControl"><?php echo $VisitDate;  ?></span> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_InnerUpdatePanel">
          <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_DateOfServiceSelection_Row_RowContainer" class="detailRowContainer">
            <div class="detailRow">
              <div class="detailLeftColumn mxDetailsLabel"> Date of Service:
                <div class="detailErrorContainer"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="detailRightColumn">
                <?php 
                $VisitDate=strtotime($query_result['DateofService']);
                echo $VisitDate=date("m-d-Y",$VisitDate);                     
                 ?>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_InformationSource_RowContainer" class="detailRowContainer detailRowOdd">
            <div class="detailRow">
              <label>
              <div class="detailLeftColumn mxDetailsLabel"> Information Source:
                <div class="detailErrorContainer"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="detailRightColumn"> <span id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_InformationSource_SourceNameLabel">User Entered</span> </div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_DiagnosingProvider_Row_RowContainer" class="detailRowContainer">
            <div class="detailRow">
              <div class="detailLeftColumn mxDetailsLabel"> Provider or Facility:
                <div class="detailErrorContainer"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="detailRightColumn"> <span><?php echo $query_result['Provider']; ?></span> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="notesSection">
            <div class="commentRow">
              <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_Comment_Row_RowContainer" class="detailRowContainer">
                <div class="detailRow">
                  <div class="detailLeftColumn mxDetailsLabel"> Notes:
                    <div class="detailErrorContainer"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="detailRightColumn"> <span><?php echo $query_result['Notes'] ?></span> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="YesNoSection">
      <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_IsShared_YesNoRow_RowContainer">
        <div class="detailRow">
          <fieldset>
            <legend class="detailLeftColumn mxDetailsLabel"> <span>Hide this item when printing or when sharing with a health care provider?</span> </legend>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="detailRightFieldsetColumn">
              <div style="display: block; margin-top: 2px;"> <span class="detailRightColumn">
                <div class="detailRightColumn">
                  <div><?php  echo $query_result['HideItem'];?></div>
                </div>
                </span> </div>
            </div>


          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="detailRow">
          <fieldset>
            <legend class="detailLeftColumn mxDetailsLabel"> <span>Do you still have this condition?</span> </legend>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="detailRightFieldsetColumn">
              <div style="display: block; margin-top: 2px;"> <span class="detailRightColumn">
                <div class="detailRightColumn">
                  <div><?php  echo $query_result['stillCondition'];?></div>
                </div>
                </span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="detailErrorContainer"> </div>
            <span class="question_mark"></span>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_ctl01">
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_EntryRightSideContainer" class="EntryRightSideContainer">
      <div class="LearnMoreDetail">
        <div class="mxRoundTable">
          <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_LearnMore_Container_headerDiv" class="mxRoundTableTitle">
            <div class="mxRoundedCap"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mxDataTableBackground">
            <div class="mxRoundedCap">
              <div class="mxRoundedMain">
                <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_LearnMore_Container_titleDiv" class="mxDataTableTitle">
                  <h2>
                    <div class="LearnMoreDetailTitle">
                      <h2>Learn More About Diabetes Mellitus</h2>
                    </div>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_LearnMore_Container_ContentDiv" class="mxDataTableContent">
                  <div class="LearnMoreDetailText">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <div id="learnMoreItem"> <img id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_LearnMore_Container_LinkRepeater_ctl00_Icon" src="images/content.png" alt="" style="border-width: 0px;"> <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_LearnMore_Container_LinkRepeater_ctl00_Link" href="javascript:PopupMultiViewer('/common/content/contentviewer.aspx%3fcui=C0011849%26topic=Diabetes+Mellitus%26etype=%26subtypes=%26contid=XIe3090mJjlQCAfxu90R%26toplink=%26topid=0%26topsrcid=0')">Articles related to Diabetes Mellitus</a>
                          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mxRoundTableFooter">
            <div class="mxRoundedCap"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="Pan" style="width: 650px; display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 100001; left: 631.5px; top: 447.5px;">
      <div class="mxModalContainer" id="ModalContainer">
        <div  class="mxHeader">
          <div>
            <div class="mxModalContentTitle">
              <h1></h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mxModalContentTitleClose"> </div>
          <div>
            <div class="mxModalContentTitleAdditional"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
              </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="modalBackground" style="display: none; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10000; width: 1263px; height: 994px;" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_ctl05_ModalDialogExtender_backgroundElement"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_CommandRow_DetailButtonRow" class="detailRow detailButtonRow"> &nbsp;
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_LobbyContent_Content_EntryRepeater_ctl00_InterfaceControl_DetailAnimator_ctl03_CommandRow_DetailButtonContainer"><script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#button").click( function(){
            var optionValue = <?php echo $conditionId ?>;
            var categoryval=1;
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getcondition.php",
            data: "category="+optionValue+"&categoryval="+categoryval,
            success: function(response){
                    jQuery("#AjaxDiv").html(response);
                    jQuery("#AjaxDiv").show();
                    jQuery("#AjaxDiv1").hide();                 
                }
            });          
        });
    });
</script>
      <div class="mxButtonOrange"> <span>
        <button class="mxClearButtonOrange" id="button" type="button"  name="button">Edit</button>
        </span> </div>
      <div class="mxButtonOrange"> <span>


      <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#button1").click( function(){
            var optionValue = <?php echo $conditionId ?>;
            var categoryval=1;
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "deletecondition.php",
            data: "category="+optionValue+"&categoryval="+categoryval,
            success: function(response){
                    jQuery("#AjaxDiv").html(response);
                    jQuery("#AjaxDiv").show();
                    jQuery("#AjaxDiv1").hide();                 
                }
            });          
        });
    });
</script>
        <button class="mxClearButtonOrange" type="button" id="button1"  value="Delete" >Delete</button>
        </span> </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>











                              </div>
                        </div>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Where is the generated HTML ?

Comment: use MVC instead of your approach

Comment: Injecting PHP code inside JavaScript code is really evil. You should at least put the PHP logic on top and set variables.

Comment: @acme can you please provide documentation supporting your belief?

Comment: @Rey Gonzales that does not make it inherently "evil".

Comment: Haha, I hope its an expression.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc - if you want your code to be maintainable.